# How many hours did you spend/spent studying for the test?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, questions, past-tense

I'm pretty confused on which sentence is grammatically correct just because online and in person, everyone says it differently:

> How many hours did you spend studying for the test?

or is it:

> How many hours did you spent studying for the test?

I know *spent* is the past but for some reason most people use "How many hours did you spend studying for the test?" Any insights?

Comment: The rule is that you only need one tense marker, and it goes on the first auxiliary verb, or on the main verb if there are no auxiliary verbs. _Did_ is an auxiliary verb and it's got a past tense marker, so you can't say past tense _spent_ after _did_; you hafta use the infinitive _spend_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar books will tell you that these two are correct:

> How many hours did you spend studying for the test?
>   AND
>   How many hours **have** you **spent** studying for the test?

But the cluster of consonants in the middle of 
*How many hours did you spe**nd st**udying for the test?* makes it almost indistinguishable from: *How many hours did you spe**nt st**udying for the test?* People write what they think they hear.